# Image Slider - CSS

Tags: css

Sou Leigo em Programação, mas preciso que as imagens fiquem por 10segundos na tela.
Já tentei alterar o CSS, mas fica sem sincronização com as alterações.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.untitled {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: rotateHue infinite 20s linear;
          animation: rotateHue infinite 20s linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.625s;
          animation-delay: 0.625s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateHue {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(270deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(270deg);
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(270deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(270deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateHue {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(270deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(270deg);
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(270deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(270deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
            filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.untitled__shutters {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150vmax;
  width: 150vmax;
  left: calc(50% - 75vmax);
  top: calc(50% - 75vmax);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: rotateFrame 10s linear infinite;
          animation: rotateFrame 10s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateFrame {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateFrame {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
.untitled__shutters:before, .untitled__shutters:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  background-color: #b3401a;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.untitled__shutters:before {
  bottom: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: openTop 5s infinite;
          animation: openTop 5s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes openTop {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.1, 1);
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.1, 1);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -65vmax, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, -65vmax, 0);
    animation-timing-functon: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -65vmax, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, -65vmax, 0);
    animation-timing-functon: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
  }
}
@keyframes openTop {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.1, 1);
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.1, 1);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -65vmax, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, -65vmax, 0);
    animation-timing-functon: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -65vmax, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, -65vmax, 0);
    animation-timing-functon: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
  }
}
.untitled__shutters:after {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: openBottom 5s infinite;
          animation: openBottom 5s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes openBottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.1, 1);
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.1, 1);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 65vmax, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 65vmax, 0);
    animation-timing-functon: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 65vmax, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 65vmax, 0);
    animation-timing-functon: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
  }
}
@keyframes openBottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.1, 1);
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.1, 1);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 65vmax, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 65vmax, 0);
    animation-timing-functon: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 65vmax, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 65vmax, 0);
    animation-timing-functon: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335);
  }
}
.untitled__slides {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #b3401a;
}
.untitled__slide {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: showHideSlide infinite 20s steps(1);
          animation: showHideSlide infinite 20s steps(1);
}
@-webkit-keyframes showHideSlide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
@keyframes showHideSlide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
.untitled__slide:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
}
.untitled__slide:nth-child(1) .untitled__slideBg {
  background-image: url(https://collab.intra.fcagroup.com/sites/cma/ict/RH/1.jpg);
}
.untitled__slide:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
          animation-delay: 5s;
}
.untitled__slide:nth-child(2) .untitled__slideBg {
  background-image: url(https://collab.intra.fcagroup.com/sites/cma/ict/RH/2.jpg);
}
.untitled__slide:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
          animation-delay: 10s;
}
.untitled__slide:nth-child(3) .untitled__slideBg {
  background-image: url(https://collab.intra.fcagroup.com/sites/cma/ict/RH/3.jpg);
}
.untitled__slide:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
          animation-delay: 15s;
}
.untitled__slide:nth-child(4) .untitled__slideBg {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/g/1500/1200?image=345);
}
.untitled__slideBg {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #b3401a;
  background-blend-mode: hard-light;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-animation: bgInOut 5s infinite;
          animation: bgInOut 5s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bgInOut {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.1);
            transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  66% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22);
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.9);
            transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.9);
  }
}
@keyframes bgInOut {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.1);
            transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  66% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22);
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.9);
            transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.9);
  }
}
.untitled__slideContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Abril Fatface", sans-serif;
  line-height: 0.8;
  letter-spacing: -0.025em;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(179, 64, 26, 0.25);
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
.untitled__slideContent span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 15vmin;
}

.button {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2vmin;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: -0.5vmin 0.5vmin 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background: transparent;
  margin-top: 5vmin;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  color: white;
  padding: 2vmin 2vmin 1.8vmin 2vmin;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-shadow: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.5vmin, -0.5vmin, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0.5vmin, -0.5vmin, 0);
  transition: all 100ms linear;
}
.button:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(1vmin, -1vmin, 0);
          transform: translate3d(1vmin, -1vmin, 0);
  box-shadow: -1vmin 1vmin 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
.button:active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Comunicacao Interna - CMA</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface|Hind:300,400,700|Roboto+Mono:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

  
<div class="untitled">
 <div class="untitled__slides">
  <div class="untitled__slide">
   <div class="untitled__slideBg"></div>
   <div class="untitled__slideContent">
    <span></span> 
    <span></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="untitled__slide">
   <div class="untitled__slideBg"></div>
   <div class="untitled__slideContent">
    
    <span></span> 
    <span></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="untitled__slide">
   <div class="untitled__slideBg"></div>
   <div class="untitled__slideContent">
    <span></span> 
    <span></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="untitled__slide">
   <div class="untitled__slideBg"></div>
   <div class="untitled__slideContent">
    <span></span> 
    <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="untitled__shutters"></div>
</div>
  
  

    <script  src="./script.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Coloque também o HTML para que assim possamos tentar reproduzir o cenário.

Comment: @Sam coloquei.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, o certo é colocar essa funcionalidade no javaScript, ficaria assim.

```
<div class="img"></div>
```

no css.

```
.ocultar{opacity:"0"}
```

no js.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('.img').classList.add('ocultar');
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Comment: adicionei o código Html e Css. Não tem nada no Java.
O que adiciono no Html, e no Css?